Book of Maccabees in original Greek
I am in search for the book of Maccabees in its original Greek. Preferably not a Christian version. I'm not even sure if this exists. I would be glad for your help.

All apocryphal books in Greek of Jewish origin were preserved by the Church. Even various critical/academic editions are based on manuscripts preserved by Christians. Jews didn't or weren't able to preserve those texts themselves.

Isn’t it presumed that 1 Maccabees was originally written in Hebrew?

@Harel13 so the books quoted by all the rabbis are of Christian provenance?

@JoelK if it was in Hebrew, wouldn't we know what Maccabee means? I.e. מקבי vs מכבי

Which books of Maccabees? There exists a total of 8 such books according to wikipedia, some have originals in Greek, some in Syriac, some in Arabic.

@YDJ I'm concerned with the first 4

@Shababnik The original Hebrew is no longer extant, so I’m not sure what you are asking…

@Shababnik what do you mean by "all the rabbis"? In any case, rabbis who refer to the various Books of Maccabees are referring to texts preserved by Christians. They were not created by Christians, but were preserved by them.

@Harel13 I wasn't sure how to phrase it properly... anyway I'm assuming we trust these texts

@Shababnik to my knowledge, it's agreed nowadays, both by rabbis and academics, that the texts weren't influenced by Christians.

Small clarification: We don't know how different the original Hebrew version of 1 Maccabees was from the Greek translation. But the Greek texts, certainly those of 1-2 Maccabees, aren't considered to have been influenced by Christians, i.e., that they edited in anachronistic Christian messages.

@Harel13 Got it. I'm not sure the same can be said of other texts such as the septuagint, which was written in close proximity (i believe at most a couple hundred years) to the writings of the Maccabees

What about the 3,4th books? Which have more of a hashkafic message

I'm not familiar enough with the other two. We no longer have the original Septuagint. The one we have is actually based on versions created by Church Fathers. It's a very problematic text. I've discussed it in a few answers here. As for other Greek texts, כל מקרה לגופו, every text should be analyzed on its own. We're talking about different authors, different origins, different contexts, and sometimes even vastly different modes of preservation.

The Books of Maccabees are printed with the Septuagint, of which the standard edition is that of Rahlfs (also published in an editio major), or Swete.

This one includes Maccabees I - IV. There are also books V - VIII according to wikipedia
